# Ubuntu - connect a monitor to a laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is there any way, how to make connecting monitor to my laptop as easy as it is e.g. in Windows? Just plug-n-play?

I`ve just installed last version of Ubuntu and then connect monitor. After connecting monitor nothing happend (my laptop LCD doesn`t get blinked and it doesn`t try to use the monitor as a second one).

So i went to Monitors configuration, where i saw "Mirror screens".

I`ve unchecked "Same image in all monitors" and applied, also nothing happend. The monitor is still just black.

Is there any application which would make this stuff easier for me?

I have HP ProBook 5320m with some Intel HD graphic card inside and 21.5" LG W2240T-PN monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a standalone app to do this if the bulitin isn't working for you. I've hacked this together, and I use it whenever I run dual-monitors.

I know you were looking for something builtin, but I've found that this works well enough in practice and I've never quite found any of the builtins to my liking anyway. Plus, this works with any system running Python and pygtk-2.x, irregardless of windowing system.

The script itself is now hosted with [my Gists](https://gist.github.com/1324064) - the code is cleaned up significantly and been somewhat decrufted. Also, it now lacks a tray mode - just run it with `pyrandr.py`.

Comment: I tried your script and it is unfortunately not functional:

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ python file.py tray
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 216, in <module>
    seticon()
  File "file.py", line 209, in seticon
    gtk.main()
KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: I modified this script slightly for presentation - I'll update it with the original. I noticed the icon flickering as well.

Answer (score 0):

After connection and starting the monitor; on the main menu "Panel" click System -> Preferences -> Display and there you can auto-detect the monitor type, switch displays individually on/off, change the resolutions, refresh rates, and drag the monitor icons around so that you have side-by-side displays of an "extended desk top" or the external display 'mirroring' the lap-top display. For more details see 
http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/stable/goscustdesk-70.html.en

Comment: He just said he's using the latest version of Ubuntu, which means he's probably using Unity, not Gnome.  There is no Gnome Menu Panel...  multi-monitor support in Unity is very buggy, borderline broken...

Comment: i`m sorry i didn`t mention that, i am using 11.04 Natty Narwhal

Answer (score 0):

I should say that using `xrandr` is "as easy as Windows", but you do have to learn how to use `xrandr` first... that said, once you've learnt it you'll have a level of command over your monitors that will make Windows users turn away in shame. Reflection anyone?