# Connect and disconnect a monitor in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-11.10

I replaced OSX with Linux on my Macbook Pro. When I had OSX in it, I could connect an external monitor and it would be automatically detected and used. When I disconnected it, everything would move to the laptop monitor.

This doesn't happen in Ubuntu. How can we fix this people?

Answer (score 0):

You can add resolution modes manualy in xrandr. However if you use latest ubuntu you should be able to do it in GUI way.

Comment: … so how does one do this in a GUI way?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/301758/ubuntu-connect-a-monitor-to-a-laptop/302150#302150). It involves installing `pygtk` and running [this script](https://gist.github.com/1324064).

I'm not an Ubuntu user - there's probably a way to do this without external tools, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

With Ubuntu 16.04 and newer, a newly connected monitor is automatically detected.

I still get a glitch when disconnecting it - the application windows from the external monitor don't get placed back to the main monitor. To fix this, I simply run "Displays" app from Ubuntu's main menu. There is no need to change any settings in the app, Ubuntu refreshes the status of monitors when opening it, so I just close it once it opens.